# Question about the limitations of POSTGRESQL (list making)

Tags: postgresql

I have this code that gives me a list of where user can go:

```
SELECT place_name,user_id,user_name
    FROM code.place, code.user
    WHERE (place.place_id, user_id) NOT IN(
        SELECT place_id, user_id
            FROM code.visit
            WHERE visit.user_id BETWEEN 1 AND 15
            AND age(date) <= interval '4 months'
    )
    AND user_id BETWEEN 1 AND 15
```

I want to know if it would be possible to make a code that could take this list and define the following:

```
Select 2 places to user with id=1

Select 1 places to user with id=2

Select 3 places to user with id=3
```

Based on the list above, of course (AND without repeated places, as the list above gives repeated places). The result should look like this.

```
place_name|user_id|user_name|
COSCO     |1      | james   |
WALMART   |1      | james   |
MALL      |2      | carlos  |
TARGET    |3      | jane    |
7ELEVEN   |3      | jane    |
NESTLE    |3      | jane    |
```

I am sorry if it's a silly question but I am new to PostegreSQL (any SQL at all) and need to know the limitations of this language to do a project that I have (I am a intern).

The code "SELECT" gives me the "table" below. The first "table" is what I need to create.

```
    place_name|user_id|user_name|
1   NESTLE    |1      | james   |
2   7ELEVEN   |1      | james   |
3   MALL      |1      | james   |
4   TARGET    |1      | james   |
5   COSCO     |2      | carlos  |
6   WALMART   |2      | carlos  |
7   TARGET    |2      | carlos  |
8   7ELEVEN   |2      | carlos  |
9   NESTLE    |2      | carlos  |
10  COSCO     |3      | jane    |
11  WALMART   |3      | jane    |
12  MALL      |3      | jane    |
```

---

The CREATE TABLE code looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE code.place ( 
   place_id VARCHAR(8), 
   place_name VARCHAR (50),
   CONSTRAINT pk_place_id PRIMARY KEY (place_id)
);


CREATE TABLE code.user ( 
   user_id VARCHAR(3), 
   user_name VARCHAR (50),
   CONSTRAINT pk_user_id PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE code.visit ( 
   user_id VARCHAR(3), 
   place_id VARCHAR(8),
   date DATE,
   CONSTRAINT pk_user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES SCHEMA.user,
   CONSTRAINT pk_place_id FOREIGN KEY (place_id) REFERENCES code.place,
        EXCLUDE USING gist (pk_user_id WITH =, daterange(data, (data + interval '6 months')::date) WITH &&)
);
```

Comment: Could you add some sample data and perhaps an explanation of how you arrive at those desired results?  I don't even see COSCO/1/JAMES in your current output, so I'm not sure how that is to be derived.

Comment: The code "SELECT" gives me the second "table". The first "table" is what I need to create.